# Why my link_to doesn't show target option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method in my UsersHelper which create a link with generated address

```
module UsersHelper
    def random_site(generated_site)
       link_to(generated_site  , generated_site, target: "_blank")
    end 
end
```

i use this method helper in my view like this :

```
= wrap(item.content.gsub(item.origine_url, random_site(item.random_address)))
```

here for example if my `item.content` contains :

```
foobar text foobar text www.stackoverflow.com
```

which means my `item.origine_url == www.stackoverflow.com`

content will be replaced by :

```
foobar text foobar text www.random_generated_address.com
```

problem here is with `target: "_blank"` that i added before in my `link_to` which is in **method helper**, i can't see `target="_blank"` in my html link, and when i click the link, it's opened in the same page !

when i do only :

```
= random_site(item.random_address)
```

it works fine , so what's the problem with `= wrap(item.content.gsub(item.origine_url, random_site(item.random_address)))` ??

my wrap method is :

```
def wrap(content)
    sanitize(raw(content.split.map{ |s| wrap_long_string(s) }.join(' ')))
  end

  private

    def wrap_long_string(text, max_width = 60)
      zero_width_space = "&#8203;"
      regex = /.{1,#{max_width}}/
      (text.length < max_width) ? text :
                                  text.scan(regex).join(zero_width_space)
    end
```

Comment: Have you verified that `item.content` infact has `item.origine_url`?  I would first start by testing out the `gsub`, then `random_site()` then the `wrap`.

Comment: @vinodadhikary i found the solution, the problem was in wrap method, because of sanitize method, i want to permit "a" tag and "href, target" attributes :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in wrap() method, i want to permit some tag and attributes in sanitize method which is inside it, my code will be :

```
def wrap(content)
    sanitize(raw(content.split.map{ |s| wrap_long_string(s) }.join(' ')), :tags => %w(a), :attributes => %w(target href))
end
```